# How to perform partial matching on _id in Elastic search

Tags: json, elasticsearch, sense

I am trying to perform a partial word matching on the `_id` field in my Elastic search instance.

After searching the official documentation I found out that the best way to do this is to create a n-gram analyzer, so using `Sense` I did this:

```
PUT /index2
{"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1, 
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "partial_filter": { 
                "type":     "ngram",
                "min_gram": 2,
                "max_gram": 20
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "partial": {
                "type":      "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "partial_filter" 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

I have tried to test the analyzer using :

```
POST /index2/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "partial",
  "text": "brown fox"
}
```

And it worked as expected producing proper combinations.
The next step should be to apply the analyzer to the relevant fields,so I tried to do this:

```
PUT /index2/_mapping/type2
{
    "type2": {
        "properties": {
            "_id": {
                "type":     "string",
                "analyzer": "partial"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i am getting an error:

> "reason": "Field [_id] is defined twice in [type2]"

Probably because _id field gets created during the `index2` creation along with the analyzer.

So my question is how can I use the partial search on the _id field?
Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any way that you could index the id into another field and use that one?

Comment: Yes I could do this , but that would mean to re-index every document...
If it is possible to use the '_id' partial matching it would be most effective..

Comment: What kind of data do you have in your ids that would require this functionality?

Comment: Hi Val, I have string type data on the _id field (up to 3 words mostly) and i would like find out whether or not is possible to do a partial matching on them. I understand that your suggestion is a more efficient or proper way to go but if it is possible to have such functionality on the_id field it would be preferable in this case! Let me point out that this is not a production server but an experimental one.

Comment: have you tried the `prefix` query on the `_id` field?

Comment: Yes I tried to, but I am getting an error `Can only use prefix queries on keyword and text fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id`